# mySQL Find missing entries from duplicated rows

Tags: mysql, duplicates, multiple-entries

mySQL query - I have a table 'database'.'table_product_options' containing around 1000 rows. This table should contain 4x rows for each 'product_id' - the same product assigned to each 'customer_group' (illustrated below). This should equate to ~250 rows per customer_group.

However, I have run a COUNT on each **'customer_group'**, and found that there are a handful of missing entries for groups *a*+ *c*  (250 rows total each for groups *b*+ *d*, but only 245 rows for groups *a*+ *c*).

```
+----------------+----------------+
| product_id     | customer_group |
+----------------+----------------+
|       1        |        a       | }
|       1        |        b       | }
|       1        |        c       | }-each 'product_id' has 4x 'customer_group' attached
|       1        |        d       | }
|       2        |        a       |
|       2        |        b       |
|       2        |        c       | << 1 missing entry (customer_group = d)
|       3        |        a       | << 3 missing entries (customer_group = b, c, d)
+----------------+----------------+
```

How can I run a SELECT query (or alternative) to display which **'product_id'** has less than 4 rows assigned? Or, in other words, how can I find the missing entries?

I have tried many different queries including SELECTs combined with WHERE NOT EXIST and etc but I am running out of ideas. I have modified a dozen stackoverflow answers but none are quite suitable, and haven't been able to modify the syntax to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated (as I anticipate the same problem cropping up again in the future..). I may end up scouring the table by eye!

Comment: Ideally, what would the result look like?

Comment: The chosen answer (below) just lists the "odd ones out" displaying the product_id's in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select product_id, count(customer_group)
from table_product_options
group by product_id
having count(customer_group) < 4
```

You might have to switch the having and group by line.  I get the order confused.

Answer (score 0):

Compose the possible combination for finding missed group.

```
select product_id, indicator, case when indicator = 1 
                                   case when availe = 'a' then 'b,c,d' 
                                   when availe = 'b' then 'a,c,d' 
                                   when availe = 'c' then 'a,b,d'
                                   else 'a,b,c' end
                               case when indicator = 2
                                     case when availe = 'a,b' then 'c,d'
                 //Like wise Give the possible combination for finding missing group
                                end as missing_group 
 from
(select product_id, count(customer_group) as indicator, group_concat(customer_group) as availe
from table_product_options
group by product_id) a where indicator < 4
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! I chose the other answer as it came first and is the most simple solution. This looks more in depth but will try it out as well :)